# imgur images not showing in account

Tags: php, imgur

I create an image gallery application using PHP.For hosting i used imgur, its working fine on my site. I can upload and see the images from my application but problem is when i login my imgur account i can't see any images there.

### HTML code

```
<form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    Choose Image : <input name="img" size="35" type="file"/><br/>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

### PHP code

```
<?
$img = $_FILES['img'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($img['name'] == '') {
        echo "<h2>An Image Please.</h2>";
    } else {
        $filename  = $img['tmp_name'];
        $client_id = "client_id****";
        $handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
        $data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        $pvars     = array(
            'image' => base64_encode($data)
        );
        $timeout   = 30;
        $curl      = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id
        ));
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $pms = json_decode($out, true);
        $url = $pms['data']['link'];
        if ($url != "") {
            echo "<h2>Uploaded Without Any Problem</h2>";
            echo "<img src='$url'/>";
        } else {
            echo "<h2>There's a Problem</h2>";
            echo $pms['data']['error'];
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload to a specific imgur account, you need to follow the OAuth authentication and authorization process outlined [here](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2).  Otherwise the image will just be uploaded without being attached to a user.